# Define AND, OR, NOT operators in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to define a prolog program which gives the truth table for a logic formula like this:

> (a or non (b and c))

where the logic variables can only have true or false value, and the only operators are AND,OR and NOT.
The program should behave like this:

```
table(a and (b or non a)).

[a, b]
[v, v] v
[v, f] f
[f, v] f
[f, f] f
yes
```

What i did is define the 3 operators ,but i dont know how to continue. Can you help me ?

```
:- op(30,fx,non).
:- op(100,xfy,or).
:- op(100,xfy,and).
```

Comment: Is `(a or not (b and c)` the exact format you must use? are you sure there is no uppercase variable? If so, you first need to parse the input to collect all variables; when you have your variables, generate all combinations of true/false for all inputs; then, evaluate the expression for each combination of inputs and print a line for each result. But first, how would you write a rule that represents the and(A,B,R) relationship? A, B and R can be either v/f (vrai/faux). Please try this first.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know how to deal with the 3 defined operators. What can i do to obtain that (b and c ), if both true give true as result, so that not(b and c) gives false, and so on ?

Answer (score 1):

Not going for the full solution, but here are some hints.

#### Basic approach

```
% fact: truth value "v" is satisfiable in all environments.
sat(v,_).

% rule: and(X,Y) is satisfiable in environment E iff both X and Y are sat in E
sat(and(X,Y),E) :- sat(X,E), sat(Y,E).
```

#### Bindings

```
sat(Var, E) :- 
  (member(Var:Value,E) -> 
    Value = v 
  ; throw(unknown_variable(Var,E))).
```

Example:

```
[eclipse 6]: sat(o,[o:v]).

Yes (0.00s cpu)
[eclipse 7]: sat(o,[o:f]).

No (0.00s cpu)
[eclipse 8]: sat(o,[u:v]).
uncaught exception in throw(unknown_variable(o, [u : v]))
Abort
```

#### Enumeration

Define a rule (*binding*) which binds a variable to a value non-deterministically, and another one (*bindings*) which binds a list of symbols (atoms) to a list of bindings.

```
% Two different solution possible when binding Var
binding(Var, Var:v).
binding(Var, Var:f).

% Lists of bindings
bindings([],[]).
bindings([V|VL],[B|BL]) :-
  binding(V,B), 
  bindings(VL,BL).
```

For example:

```
[eclipse 9]: bindings([a,b,c],L).

L = [a : v, b : v, c : v]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ? ;

L = [a : v, b : v, c : f]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more) ? ;

L = [a : v, b : f, c : v]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more) ? ;

L = [a : v, b : f, c : f]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 4, maybe more) ? ;

L = [a : f, b : v, c : v]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 5, maybe more) ? ;

L = [a : f, b : v, c : f]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 6, maybe more) ? ;

L = [a : f, b : f, c : v]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 7, maybe more) ? ;

L = [a : f, b : f, c : f]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 8)
```

#### Operators

First, you could declare the following `and` predicate:

```
and(0,0,0).
and(1,0,0).
and(0,1,0).
and(1,1,1).
```

The rule can be applied as `and(X,Y,R)`, and `R` is the result of the `and` operation. The same can be done with `or`, etc.

Your declaration:

```
:- op(100,xfy,and).
```

... allows to write `X and Y` instead of `and(X,Y)`, but notice how there is no third argument here. With the [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/) environment, the operator notation is also used in conjunction with [`is/2`](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/arithmetic/is-2.html) to evaluate arithmetic expressions. Since the above `add` predicate deals with numbers, the following works:

```
X is 0 and 1.
```

The above unifies X with 0.

Comment: Thanks. I've understood everything , except how can i represent the relation between AND,OR and NOT. Can you help me ? For example , is it possible to define an operator that returns an integer ? 
a AND b --> return 1  if a == 1 and b == 1

Comment: SWI Prolog and GNU Prolog do not allow you to define arithmetic operators and functions. So `X is 0 and 1.` will fail due to `and` not being recognized. I'm not sure if there's a popular flavor of Prolog that allows it.

Comment: @lurker I am not sure how Eclipse CLP is popular, I'll add a note in the answer